# AttributeError: class Home has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: python, flask-restful

I'm using `Flask Restful` and I want to render an `HTML file` on the root endpoint:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
app = Flask( __name__, static_url_path = '', static_folder = "docs" )
api = Api(app, catch_all_404s=True)
class Home():
    def get(self):
        return app.send_static_file( 'index.html' )
api.add_resource(Home, '/')
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
    api.add_resource(Home, '/')
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 404, in add_resource
    self._register_view(self.app, resource, *urls, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 444, in _register_view
    resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint, *resource_class_args,
AttributeError: class Home has no attribute 'as_view'
```

How to render a static file in `Flask Restful` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Flask Restful Documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing); as an example you can find the following in the documentation:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

todos = {}

class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

As you can see above, one thing you're missing surely is the inheritance from `Resource`.

Comment: You're welcome @Souad, don't forget to mark it as the answer.